Does the order of Selection, Projection and Join matter?
Trainers:
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Age} & \textbf{Team}  \\ 
\hline
\text{Pep Guardiola} & 53 & \text{Manchester City}  \\ 
\hline
\text{Arne Slot} & 46 & \text{Liverpool} \\ 
\hline
\text{Vincent Kompany} & 38 & \text{Bayern Munich} \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
Teams:
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Pot} \\ 
\hline
\text{Manchester City} & \text{Attack} & 1 \\ 
\hline
\text{Liverpool} & \text{Attack} & 1 \\ 
\hline
\text{Bayern Munich} & \text{Defense} & 1 \\ 
\hline
\text{Chelsea} & \text{Defense} & 2 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
$\pi_{\text{Name}}(\sigma_{\text{Type}=\text{′Attack′}}(\text{Trainers} \bowtie \rho_{\text{Name} \rightarrow \text{Team}}(\text{Teams})))$
$\pi_{\text{Name}}(\text{Trainers} \bowtie \rho_{\text{Name} \rightarrow \text{Team}}(\sigma_{\text{Type}=\text{′Attack′}}(\text{Teams})))$
I previously had a discussion whether these two queries do the same. I think essentially they do in this case. But is that generally true? Or could one come up with an example where one would fail. It appears that the second one is somewhat more efficient however and thus the first one could maybe fail when the dataset is large.

Your question asks

Is $\sigma_\phi(R)\bowtie S\equiv \sigma_\phi(R\bowtie S)$?

We have the definitions as
$\sigma_\phi(R)=\{r|r\in R,\phi(r)\}$
$R\bowtie S = \{r\cup s|r\in R, s \in S\}$
so
$\sigma_\phi(R)\bowtie S=\{r\cup s|r\in R,s\in S,\phi(r)\}$
$\sigma_\phi(R\bowtie S) = \{r\cup s|r\in R, s \in S, \phi(r\cup s)\}$
But $\phi$ is a function $R$ and undefined on $S$, so $\phi(r\cup s)=\phi(r)\lor\phi(s)=\phi(r)\lor\bot=\phi(r)$, with $\phi(s)=\bot$ vacuously.
